# VScode rg process taking all the CPU

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VScode is behaving strangely. When I checkout or pull with many changes in files, it creates many processes called `rg` that drain the CPU to 100% usage. This problem persists even if I kill the VScode, I have to manually kill the processes.

I found some old threads about disabling symlinks with `"search.followSymlinks": false` but it didn't help. Might it be some indexing problem?

I have noticed that `initializing js/ts language features` is spinning but never completes and the whole UI lags. Happy to provide more details like extensions, etc.

I couldn't find a thread with the same problem around 2021/22 so sorry if duplicated.

[image]

Comment: `rg` is [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Comment: @user is it somehow preinstalled? I tried its commands but `command not found`

Comment: Yes, it's bundled internally with the VS Code installation because VS Code uses it. In my installation (Ubuntu snap), it's under /snap/code/###/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/@vscode/ripgrep/bin/rg

Comment: Also possibly related: [Many rg commands started by vscode that consume 99% of CPUs](/q/65120743)

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried to install the rg manually and it seems it helped so far.

Comment: Interesting... In what way has it helped?

Comment: Checkout/pull/anything that triggers the indexing with bigger changes is not consuming the CPU and is not making vscode unusable. But maybe in the future, it will start again ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Previously it took some time to get to this state

Answer (score 6):

This can happen when a lot of new files are created in a directory in your workspace that is being watched for changes by VSCode, or more likely, an extension, e.g. when you build/pull/download/unzip into a directory in your workspace.

Try add the directory/ies where many files are being created to the VSCode setting `files.watcherExclude` (search for that in VSCode settings).

I found I had to include a glob that matched the relative path of the directory (i.e. relative to the top level Workspace folder), rather than the absolute path. E.g. If the top level folder that I added to my workspace was called `TopStuff` and the directory where a lot of files were being created was `TopStuff/build/` adding `**/TopStuff/build/**` didn't work, but adding `**/build/**` did.

Comment: adding my `dist` folders to `files.watcherExclude` helped, thanks!